# Почему в typescript пересечение означает то что означает объединение в теории множеств?

Tags: javascript, typescript

В Typescript'e есть две замечательные возможности(их конечно не две но я хотел бы остановится именно на двух конкретных). [Вот ссылка на оф документацию.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)
Есть тип **пересечение**(*Intersection Types*) и тип **объединение**(*Union Types*), и работают они так:

1) **Пересечение**(*Intersection Types*) - допустим есть переменная `lsp` и в коде она объявлена так:

`let psl : Person & Serializable & Loggable`,

здесь `lsp` типизируется и включает в себя все элементы типов `Person`, `Serializable` и `Loggable` одновременно. Это означает, что у объекта этого типа будут все элементы всех трёх типов, что графически можно изобразить так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) **Объединение**(*Union Types*) - тип объединение описывает значение, которое может быть одним из нескольких типов и объявляется в коде так:

```
function getSmallPet(): Fish | Bird {
    // ...
}
```

Отличается он от типа пересечения тем, что если у нас есть значение этого типа, мы можем получить доступ только к тем его элементам, которые являются **общими для всех** типов в объединении.

Мой вопрос в том что мне не понятно почему эти сущности так названы? **Пересечение** например в теории множеств наоборот включает в себя только общие для всех элементы а не как в тайпскрипте, и с **Объединением** такая же история все точно наоборот.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38855908/2881286

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov, возьмите еще во внимание, что полное название второй конструкции это `discriminated union`, дискриминационный союз (не объединение, так решили майкрософт еще с языка F#), то есть неравный союз, где какое-то множество может преобладать над другим

Answer (score 2):

Можно взглянуть на это с другой стороны.

Рассмотрим 4 набора: красные вещи, синие вещи, большие вещи и маленькие вещи.

Если *пересечь (intersect)* множества всех красных вещей и всех маленьких вещей в итоге получим *объединение (union)* свойств – все в наборе будет и красным и маленьким.

Но если взять *объединения (union)* из *красных маленьких* и *синих маленьких*, то в результате только свойство размера будет общим, поэтому в *пересечение (intersecting)* "красных маленьких" и "синих маленьких" войдут только "маленькие".

Другими словами при *объединении* области значение получим *пересечение* наборов свойств и наоборот.

<sub>перевод ответа [@RyanCavanaugh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38857724/2881286)</sub>